# Framework iOS ARC

Tags: ios, frameworks, automatic-ref-counting

I am creating a static framework and will be using it across multiple applications. In the framework code I have disable ARC flag and is set to NO.

Other projects where I will use the framework may have ARC set to YES or NO. So if there is mismatch in ARC flags in Framework and the project where the framework is used, the application crashes since it tries to deallocate something which is already de-allocated.

Is there a solution to the above issue?

Regards,

Nirav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARC is a compile time setting, so it is per-file not per-application. All you have to do is make sure your code in each file agrees with the compiler about if it's using ARC. If you want to throw an error if a file isn't using ARC when it should be, use something like:

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    #error This file should be compiled with ARC enabled
#endif
```

and similarly for detecting the opposite.

Comment: I want to add that you can do the checkARCMacro each time something's different. For example:
#ifndef __has_feature//(objc_arc)
        _text = [initText retain];
#else
        _text = initText;
#endif - That way you can build your framework for those who are, and are not using ARC.